# can I 'inner-search' most similar vectors within a FAISS index?

Tags: python, faiss

I have a FAISS index populated with 8M embedding vectors. I don't have the embedding vectors anymore, only the index, and it is expensive to recompute the embeddings.

Can I search the index for the top-k most similar vectors to each of the index's vectors?

To be more concrete, say this is how my index was populated:

```
d = 1024
N = 100
embeddings = np.random.rand(N, d)
ids = range(N)
index = faiss.index_factory(
    d, 'IDMap,Flat', faiss.METRIC_INNER_PRODUCT
)
index.add_with_ids(embeddings, ids)
```

I would like to get `D, I` such that:

```
D, I = index.search(embeddings, k)
```

but I don't have access to `embeddings` anymore, I only have the `index`.

I tried using `index.reconstruct()` to get back my (approximated?) embeddings but I run into

```
RuntimeError: Error in virtual void 
faiss::Index::reconstruct(faiss::Index::idx_t, float*) const at /root/miniconda3/conda-bld/faiss-pkg_1613228717761/work/faiss/Index.cpp:57: reconstruct not implemented for this type of index
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all seems like you forgot `train()` your `embeddings` before `add()` it.

What is about your question you can just copy `embeddings` before adding it into the index.

Comment: I did train the embeddings of course, and that is the expensive part that I don't want to do again. That is why I was hoping to be able to search top similarities 'within' the index without having to compute the embeddings again. The code that I posted uses random embeddings but that is just to show how I have populated the index